# xpath in lxml to find id number based on href

Tags: python, regex, lxml

I'm trying to rewrite someones library to parse some xml returned with requests. However they use lxml in a way I'm not used to. I believe it's using regular expression to find the data and while most of the library provided works, it doesn't work when the site being parsed has the file id in a list structure. Essnetially I get a page back and I'm looking for an id that matches the href athlete number. So say I want to just get id's for athlete 567377.

```
</div>
</a></div>
<ul class='list-entries'>
<li class='entity-details feed-entry' id='Activity-123120999590'>
<div class='avatar avatar-athlete avatar-default'>
<a class='avatar-content' href='/athletes/567377' >
</a>
</div>

</li>
<li class='entity-details feed-entry' id='Activity-16784940202'>
<div class='avatar avatar-athlete avatar-default'>
<a class='avatar-content' href='/athletes/5252525'>
</a>
</div>
```

The code:

```
    lst_group_activity = parser.xpath(".//li[substring(@id, 1, 8)='Activity']")
```

Provides all list items perfectly but for all activities. I want to only have the one related to the right athlete. The library uses the following to use an @href to select the right athlete.

```
    lst_athlethe_act_in_group_activity = parser.xpath(".//li[substring(@id, 1, 8)='Activity']/*[@href='/athletes/"+athlethe_id+"']/..")
```

However, this never seems to work. It finds the activity but then throws them all away.

Is there a better way to get this working? Any tutorial that can point me in the right direction to correlate to the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with the `href` attribute isn't an immedite child of your `li` element, so your xpath is failing.  You're matching:

```
.//li/*[@href="..."]
```

You want:

```
.//li/div/a[@href="..."]
```

(You could match `*` instead of `a` if you think another element might contain the `href` attribute, and you can match against `.//li//a[@href="..."]` if you think the path to the `a` element might not always be `li/div/a`).

So to find the `li` element:

```
parser.xpath(".//li[substring(@id, 1, 8)='Activity']/div/a[@href='/athletes/%s']/../.." % '5252525')
```

But you can also write that without the `../..`:

```
parser.xpath(".//li[substring(@id, 1, 8)='Activity' and div/a/@href='/athletes/%s']" % '5252525')
```